Find and classify the singularities of $\frac{\sin(z)}{2z^3+z^4}$

Find and classify the singularities of $\frac{\sin(z)}{2z^3+z^4}$

This is what I've done:
We see that $2z^3+z^4=z^3(2+z)$ and when $z^3(2+z)=0$ we have $z_0=-2, z_1=0$
these are our singularities.
Expanding $\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(2+z)}$:
$\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(2+z)}=\frac{1}{z^3(2+z)}\left(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+...\right)=\frac{1}{z^2(2+z)}-\frac{1}{3!(2+z)}+\frac{z^2}{5!(2+z)}-\frac{z^4}{7!(2+z)}+...$
Hence $z_0=-2$ is an essential singularity, and $z_1=0$ is a pole of order 2.
Is this correct? thanks in advance!
Edit: Also, would the residue of $z_0=-2$ be $\frac{1}{3!}$?

$-2$ is pole of oder $1$ since $(z+2) \frac {\sin (z)} {2z^{3}+z^{4}} \to \frac {\sin (-2) } {(-2)^{3}}=\frac  18 \sin (2)$ as $ z \to -2$. The residue is equal to this  limit.
You are right about the singularity at $0$.
Residue at $0$ is coefficient of $z^{2}$ in the product $(z-z^{3}/3!+z^{5}/5!+...)\frac  1 2 (1-z/2+(z/2)^{2}-(z/3)^{3}+...)$ which is $-\frac 1 4$.
Remark: If you use the formula for the residue at $0$ you will get an indeterminate form after differentiation and you will have to apply L'Hopital's Rule twice to get the value at $0$. This is  a bit complicated, so I recommend using series expansions to directly read out the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$.

I see, thank you! When I expanded out the function, how do I know to only focus on $(z-z_1)=z$ here and not also $(z-z_0)=(z+2)$? Thanks.

If you have function of the form $\frac {g(z)} {z-z_0}$ where $g$ is analytic near $z_0$ then you can immediately conclude that $z_0$ is a pole of order $1$. @Tay

Oh, I see thank you!

Hi there, I am trying to calculate the Res(0), but I am getting undefined? Here's what I've done:
$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{1!}\cdot \frac{d}{dz}\cdot z^2 \cdot \frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(2+z)}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z(2+z)\cos(z)-\sin(z)(2+2z)}{z^2(2+z)^2}=$undefined

@Tay I have now computed the residue at $0$ also.

Sorry to bother you, but I thought that the residue is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)}$? but I know here we are not given the centre so I am just wondering how you know that the residue is the coefficient of $z^2$ thanks!

Here $z_0$ is $0$. Notice that I have omitted $\frac 1 {z^{3}}$ in the product. When you put in this factor the coefficient of $z^{2}$ becomes coefficient of $\frac  1z =\frac  1{ z-0}$. @Luke

Sorry to keep this going, but I don't understand where the product you provided comes from. I see that the first thing being multiplied is $sin(z)$ laurent series, but after this I am confused sorry

I expanded $\frac 1 {2+z}\equiv \frac 1  2\frac  1 {1+(z/2)}$ as $\frac  1 2 (1-(z/2)+(z/2)^{2}-(z/3)^{3}+...)$. @Luke

Ohh I see! Thank you. I was confused because in this question they do not tell us the centre. Does this mean we can choose the point that we expand around? Thank you so much by the way you are extremely helpful.

Also, when I try to calculate the $Res(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{(2-1)!} \frac{d}{dz} z^2 \frac{\sin(z)}{z(2+z)}$ I get 0 which cannot be true as the residue of a pole can't be zero. Do you have any idea why this formula does not work In this case? Or if I am doing something wrong?
